# zipping a file created by a progress application

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Is there a way to zip/compress (with progress code) a file that I am creating with a progress application. More words words words words words.

Comment: if not, that is a good answer too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try OUTPUT THROUGH zip > VALUE(File).

and to unzip it INPUT THROUGH unzip -c VALUE(file ) BINARY NO-CONVERT.

Comment: Hi Sushil,
Can you please give a detial example for this..?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an external library for that, and then call it from the ABL language. Look for the HLC (High Level Calls) in the reference manual.

The usual tool for "light" zipping is mzip.

Be aware that not all 64-bit platform versions can make HLC calls due to limitations in their AVM binary structure being 32 bit.